# Document multiple enumeration/variables with the same description in doxygen

Tags: doxygen

Is it possible to document multiple enumeration/variables with the same documentation?

For example:

```
enum
{
   /// Description of Values
   VALUE_1 = 0,
   VALUE_2 = 1,
   VALUE_3 = 2
};
```

This results only VALUE_1 getting described by the doxygen description, when in reality, I want all three values to have the same description. The only way to get around this is copy and paste the description for every value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Member groups](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/grouping.html#memgroup) may be what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks, but it sorta of works. However, it gives me a good place to start.

Answer (score 1):

You can document the whole enum instead of the individual values.

```
/// Description of Values
enum
{
   VALUE_1 = 0,
   VALUE_2 = 1,
   VALUE_3 = 2
};
```