# How do I make doxygen extract enum values without documenting each member?

Tags: doxygen

I have an enum that is straightforward and does not require to have each member documented. 
I'd still like all members in the documentation so people can see the possible values.

Is there a way to make doxygen to extract all members of enums without setting it to EXTRACT_ALL?

Enum in Question:

```
/// \brief This enum holds all normal and special keys
enum Key
{
   KEY_A = 'A',
   KEY_B = 'B',
   // etc
};
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Document multiple enumeration/variables with the same description in doxgen](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3536033/document-multiple-enumeration-variables-with-the-same-description-in-doxgen)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [member grouping](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/grouping.html#memgroup) and the [`DISTRIBUTE_GROUP_DOC`](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/config.html#cfg_distribute_group_doc) configuration file option.

From the `DISTRIBUTE_GROUP_DOC` documentation:

> If member grouping is used in the documentation and the `DISTRIBUTE_GROUP_DOC` tag is set to `YES`, then doxygen will reuse the documentation of the first member in the group (if any) for the other members of the group. By default all members of a group must be documented explicitly.

Also, remember to [have `\file` somewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1717941/623518).